# TypeScript Filter out types from type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I would like to remove a subset of types from a type, such as here in the following code where I want to exclude `undefined` from the union of `undefined | numbers`, supposedly resulting in a type that consists of just the remaining type of `numbers`:

```
type RemoveUndefined<T> = T extends undefined | infer R ? R : T;
type numbersOnly = RemoveUndefined<undefined | number> // undefined | number
```

This doesn't seem to work though and I am wondering what I am doing wrong, or if this is even possible at all. Thanks

Comment: Just a sidenote in the case of removing `undefined`. There is `Required` as the counterpart to `Partial` that removes undefined from its children via `-?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to remove a type from a union type, in which case Typescript has a helper function for that: `Exclude`

```
type RemoveUndefined<T> = Exclude<T, undefined>
type NumbersOnly = RemoveUndefined<undefined | number> // number
```

Documentation for Exclude [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html)