# How to Omit a string in a String Literal in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, string-literals

I know we can use `Omit<>` to type a certain object without specific props.
I was hoping we could also use this for string literals:

```
type possibleStrings = 'A' | 'B' | 'C'

type AorB = Omit<possibleStrings, 'C'>
```

But when trying to use something like this in a function for its params, I get this error:

> Type 'Pick' cannot be used as an index type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript Filter out types from type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56138894/typescript-filter-out-types-from-type)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use `Exclude` for omitting a single string in a String Literal.

```
type MyStringLiteral = 'A' | 'B' | 'C'

type AorB = Exclude<MyStringLiteral, 'C'>
```

Comment: interesting that the `Omit` utility doesnt work

Comment: @kevin yes, the `Omit` utility seems to only work on object types.